# Android Studio - Video Volume Low

Tags: android, android-webview

I have taken a web page which has several videos that show in modals and put it in a WebView. When I open this page on my laptop I get full volume. When I launch the app and try to view the video I don't see video controls and the sound on the tablet is turned all the way up, yet it is very quiet. What am I missing here?

**The WebView**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView=findViewById(R.id.webviewid);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}

}
```

Comment: are you sure that `the sound on the tablet is turned all the way up` in the multimedia channel? If yes, then it is probably the way WebView is decoding video

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko the volume slider is all the way up

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score -1):

Turn JavaScript On for the WebView.

`mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: yeah, I have that enabled and the javascript works fine for the sticky/scrolling nav and modals. It's the sound that is the issue.

Comment: @cmrussell sound here I think is not the main issue. Main issue is not showing video controls. If you can see controls, there might be an option to increase sound from there

Comment: fair enough. i have java script enabled though.

Comment: @cmrussell please add the WebView class for better understanding

Comment: it has been added @Touhidul Islam

Comment: @cmrussell are you actually loading from assets folder or its just a placeholder?

Comment: I am actually loading from the assets folder